# What is the substitute for getHibernateTemplate().find() as it is deprecated?

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate

While coding we encountered a deprication warning for getHibernateTemplate().find(); can any one suggest another method or substitute code for this issue.
We are using SpringBoot and MYSQL database.

```
String sQuery = "Select R.sPhone from Registration R where R.sPhone = " + iPhone+ "AND R.sCountry_Code= "+sCountry_Code;
        List<Object[]> resultList = (List<Object[]>) getHibernateTemplate().find(sQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the current session via sessionFactory. Access the result list as below.

```
Session sess=factory.getCurrentSession();
sess.beginTransaction();
List<Object> resultList = sess.createQuery("from Registration R").getResultList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Object> list = (List<Object>) currentSession().createQuery("your query").list();
List<Object> list = (List<Object>) currentSession().createQuery("Select R.sPhone from Registration R where R.sPhone = :sPhone ").setParameter("sPhone ", sPhone ).list();
```